Association rule extraction of time series in Python
I have a multivariate time series and I would like to extract association rules on it. I am new to this topic and I have been reviewing literature on the subject to find out how to do it.
I have seen that the first step is to dicretize the numerical time series and this can be done with the pyts library. What I haven't found is a library that allows me to extract association rules in time series.
I think that once the series is discretized, the algorithms from the mlxtend library could be used to have association rules. I'm really not sure about this and would like to know if anyone can confirm or disprove this idea.
Another thing is that, if the mlxtend library can be used, time lag would not be taken into account. For example, they could not find rules where the occurrence of the antecedent differs from the occurrence of the consequent in a time interval.
I would appreciate if someone can tell me to a python library that does this type of analysis.
Thank you very much.
